# Bootstrap's "Modal fade" incompatible with JQuery datatable?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

After including `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/datatables.min.css" />` my modal fade class div elements stop working correctly. For instance, let us consider a simple example from W3 School:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

This piece of code works correctly unless you include `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/datatables.min.css" />`.

Here is the the list of links from my Django project that I include in Django html template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap-theme.css"/>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/datatables.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/date_time.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/dataTables.bootstrap.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/global_vars.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/general_content_manager.js"></script>
```

What is the reason for this and is it possible to fix this somehow ?

Comment: Can you create a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) recreating the problem?

Comment: @Steve, Modal windows do not seem to work in JSFiddle. Here the link https://jsfiddle.net/nedgar8/e1r2Lcnx/

Comment: no described problem found https://jsfiddle.net/e1r2Lcnx/1/

Comment: Yes, indeed. In JSFiddle it works correctly. But when run in Django it works incorrectly.

Comment: Can it happen that the problem arises because I save bootstrap jquery and database css and js files to my server and than include them as internal files rather than as cdn links?

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `CSS Priorities`.Make sure you learn about the CSS priorities, There are whole lot of priorities you need to be aware of like referenced file priority, inline priorities, same file multiple styles on same element priority etc. In your case its the reference file priority, If you place the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/datatables.min.css" />` after all other css files (after your custom and bootstrap files) then this file will take the priority.

**The last file read or placed (reading from top) into the DOM will take priority over other css rules applied on same element**.

So try moving your reference above your bootstrap css and your custom css and it must work fine. Let me know if I am unclear with any point.

Comment: I tried all the possible combinations, placing <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/datatables.min.css" /> at the very beginning, as well as at the end. But I still get the same erroneous behavor. I included the list of external links in my quesiton

Comment: just a wild guess, Add the `datatables.bootstrap.min.css` as well. Possibly it might fix your issue.

Comment: Nope, still does not work. I'll try to rewrite the links as CDN links and will come back with feedback

Comment: Yes, try it and also inspect the elements and see which css rule is applying on it and breaking the UI and which file is it coming from. You can always overwrite it with your custom css. Also dont forget to post your solution if you get this fixed. I would like to know the solution as well

Comment: I don't know how stupid my solution is, but I just removed datatables.min.css and left dataTables.bootstrap.min.css. For now, everything works fine

Comment: great!! Even I was stupid to not realize that. Actually you had to use only one style .. Bad me

Comment: you can add your solution and mark it as answer. Let it help others in future

Answer (score 0):

After some discussion, I found out that I included both **datatables.bootstrap.min.css** and **datatables.min.css** in my html file which led to overlapping CSS styling. For those who use Bootstrap, include only datatables.bootstrap.min.css and DO NOT include datatables.min.css. This eventually solved the issue